# Using Cocoa / Objective-C, get currently connected network's security type in Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, networking, wireless

How do I get the security type (and other information) of the currently connected network in Airport in my Objective-C / Cocoa program?

Comment: Damn, does my question involve information that's too obscure? I really hope it's answerable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the apple documentation on the `SysConfig` API, which allows you to read that and many properties of network connections:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Reference/SysConfig/index.html

Comment: Thanks! Also, what should I use to set the system-wide proxy settings? I can't seem to find that anywhere in the API.