# Get a list of all available network interfaces (en0, en1, en2, etc) with Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, networking

In my Cocoa application I want to show the user a list of available network interfaces, like Wireshark does:

[image: O]

What is the best way of getting such a list? Does Apple provide a framework for this, or must I use a C API from the standard library or another library?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Better than wrapping ifconfig you shall check the reference of SCNetworkConfiguration which is part of Core Foundation.

Check SCNetworkInterfaceXxx functions for details.

Answer (score 1):

related answer:

[Using Cocoa / Objective-C, get currently connected network's security type in Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021095/using-cocoa-objective-c-get-currently-connected-networks-security-type-in-mac/4024962#4024962)

Answer (score 1):

The following code will get all the interfaces from OS X through System Configuration, then use standard C functions to get the IP addresses (where available).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#define IFT_ETHER 0x6

#include <SystemConfiguration/SCDynamicStore.h>

+(void)getInterfaces
{
    SCDynamicStoreRef storeRef = SCDynamicStoreCreate(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"FindCurrentInterfaceIpMac", NULL, NULL);
    CFPropertyListRef global = SCDynamicStoreCopyValue (storeRef,CFSTR("State:/Network/Interface"));
    id primaryInterface = [(__bridge NSDictionary *)global valueForKey:@"Interfaces"];

    for (NSString* item in primaryInterface)
    {
        if(get_iface_address([item UTF8String]))
        {
            NSString *ip = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:get_iface_address([item UTF8String])];
            NSLog(@"interface: %@ - %@",item,ip);
        } else
            NSLog(@"interface: %@",item);
    }
}

static char * get_iface_address (char *interface)
{
    int sock;
    uint32_t ip;
    struct ifreq ifr;
    char *val;

    if (!interface)
        return NULL;

    /* determine UDN according to MAC address */
    sock = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock < 0)
    {
        perror ("socket");
        return NULL;
    }

    strcpy (ifr.ifr_name, interface);
    ifr.ifr_addr.sa_family = AF_INET;

    if (ioctl (sock, SIOCGIFADDR, &ifr) < 0)
    {
        perror ("ioctl");
        close (sock);
        return NULL;
    }

    val = (char *) malloc (16 * sizeof (char));
    ip = ((struct sockaddr_in *) &ifr.ifr_addr)->sin_addr.s_addr;
    ip = ntohl (ip);
    sprintf (val, "%d.%d.%d.%d",
             (ip >> 24) & 0xFF, (ip >> 16) & 0xFF, (ip >> 8) & 0xFF, ip & 0xFF);

    close (sock);

    return val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <SystemConfiguration/SCDynamicStore.h>

SCDynamicStoreRef storeRef = SCDynamicStoreCreate(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"FindCurrentInterfaceIpMac", NULL, NULL);
    CFPropertyListRef global = SCDynamicStoreCopyValue (storeRef,CFSTR("State:/Network/Interface"));
    id primaryInterface = [(__bridge NSDictionary *)global valueForKey:@"Interfaces"];

    for (NSString* item in primaryInterface)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", item);
    }
```

Answer (score -4):

Your quickest and best bet is to write a wrapper for `ifconfig` command.

Comment: Potential security issues and very slow, also `ifconfig` output can change at any time and you'll be bitten!